# Bash Shell Script to copy files from source to destination

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, cp

I have a question related to my bash shell script.
Basically, I need to develop a script that copies certain files from one directory to another. Sounds easy, however, its quite a challenge for me and I hope some of you might help me.
So script should work like this:

**Scriptname Source_path Destination_path**

1) 1st Problem - the source_path might not exist and I need to echo an error message.

2) 2nd Problem - the destination path might not exist, however, I need to create some or all of the directories and then copy the files from source. Else, if directory exists, I just need to copy.

Hope this is clear and hopefully someone might help me thanks!

Comment: Is this for personal usage? As this sounds like a homework assignment. If its homework, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Greg, you are right this is for an assignment. I have the find command to look for certain extensions and skip those which are not needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the `find` command, try this:

```
find SRCPATH -exec mkdir -p DSTPATH/$(dirname "{}") \; -exec cp --parents "{}" DSTPATH \;
```

1. Each `-exec` flag begins a block of shell code to execute and `\;` terminates it.  Getting multiple commands into one `-exec` has proven problematic for me in the past, so I include two, one for each task.
2. `{}` is `find`'s syntax for the variable that indicates the current path `find` is traversing.
3. Note: The `--parents` flag is on the Linux/GNU variation of `cp`, but is not available on all versions of `cp`, so the **script below is less platform dependent**. Further, your question referred specifically to using a script.
4. Note: `SRCPATH` and `DSTPATH` represent the paths of interest. If any directory name of the source or destination contains spaces, you will have to enclose them in `" "`

---

*Alternatively* you can make a `bash` script.

```
#!/bin/bash
srcpath=$1
dstpath=$2
if [ ! -d "$srcpath" ]; then
    echo "Source path: $srcpath doesn't exist"
    exit 1
fi
mkdir -p "$dstpath"
cp -r "$srcpath/*" "$dstpath"
```

1. The `-d` flag in the `if` statement is the flag to test for the yes/no existence of the directory.  Here's some information on bash [file test operators](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/fto.html) and [other bash comparison operators](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html)
2. The `-p` flag on [mkdir](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?mkdir) tells it to fill in missing components of the path as necessary. Without the `-p`, `mkdir` expects each path component, except the final component of the path, to be present or it will fail.
3. The `-r` flag on [cp](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?cp) tells `cp` to recursively copy all the subdirectories, as well as the files indicated by `*` to the destination, creating those subdirectories as necessary.
4. Note: The " " around the paths are to protect against errors if any of the path components contain spaces.

Comment: If you exit with a negative number, the return status will actually show 255 I believe, better to use positive numbers when exiting in bash to get expected return codes later I think.  Also, testing for a dir is unnecessary when doing a mkdir -p, I think you can just do the mkdir -p without any problems, I would suspect it does the dir test internally anyhow so you would be doubling the work..

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this:

```
 find SOURCEPATH -type f | while read fname
 do 
 mkdir -p TARGETPATH/$(dirname "$fname")
 cp --parents $fname TARGETPATH
 done
```

Just substitude SOURCEPATH and TARGETPATH and you're good. `find` will display an errormessage if SOURCEPATH does not exist (1) and `mkdir -p` will create the directories.

Comment: @Allaboutthatbase2 The message does contain `"sourcepath": No such file or directory`. I think, this is clear enough and I don't think, that's worth a downvote :-(.

Comment: @steffen It's a cool trick. You still complicated it quite a bit.  Why not just use the `find ` command itself without all the bash piping and reading?  I updated my answer with a variation.  The other issue is the `--parents` flag on `cp` is Linux (or perhaps POSIX or GNU) specific

Comment: The while loop and pipe is for spaces in fname; the question doesn't sound like empty directories are to be copied (he's talking about files, not the directory tree), that's why i chose this solution. And third: this question is tagged with bash, so --parents parameter will be available.

Comment: bash has nothing to do with it. bash also runs on Solaris and Mac OS X, and cp on those OSes doesn't have the `--parents` flag.

Answer (score 1):

This script creates the whole directory structure in `$2` including empty folders from `$1`:

```
#!/bin/sh
[ -z "$2" ] && { echo "Usage: $0 SOURCE DEST"; exit 1; }
[ ! -d "$1" ] && { echo "'$1' does not exist or isn't a directory"; exit 1; }
cp -r "$1" "$2"
```

If empty directories should be skipped, you need some more logic; unless `rsync` is available:

```
#!/bin/sh
[ -z "$2" ] && { echo "Usage: $0 SOURCE DEST"; exit 1; }
[ ! -d "$1" ] && { echo "'$1' does not exist or isn't a directory"; exit 1; }
rsync -mr "$1" "$2"
```

Explanation:

- The line with `-z` verifies that the second argument is not empty
- The line with `! -d` verifies that the directory from first argument exists
- `cp -r` copies recursively
- `rsync -mr` copies recursively but skips empty directories
- [`&&`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Lists) and [`||`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Lists) are widely used substitutions for conditional statements (because they're short)

Answer (score 0):

Set Variables for arguments one and two, source and dest respectively..

```
src_dir=$1
dest_dir=$2
```

Check if directory exists if not exit

```
[[ -d $src_dir ]] || { echo "source dir not exist"; exit 1 ; }
```

Create all dirs needed in path

```
mkdir -p $dest_dir
```